# Screenshot using the terminal command

Tags: command-line, screenshot

I want to take screenshot using command in all ubuntu version without install packages. There is an any possibility ?

Comment: You don't need to install any packages - the tool is in the system by default. The simplest way is to press the `Print Scrn` key and there are other options [see this reference](https://itslinuxfoss.com/take-screenshot-linux/)

Comment: If you are looking for a terminal command, you must install packages since the default screenshot software in Ubuntu does not support terminal commands, to my knowledge. You can try installing `gnome-terminal` which supports various commands.

Answer (score 1):

"In all ubuntu versions" is the tricky part here. In older releases you could use `gnome-screenshot` to do this. But more recent releases of Ubuntu don't have that binary, as the screenshot function is built into the desktop GUI.

One option is to use the `scrot` (SCReenshOT) program, which has been around for years. It's in the repository as the `scrot` package. I know you said you can't install packages, but `scrot` is a single binary. So if you can get the tiny binary onto the machine, you can take a screenshot:

The source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/resurrecting-open-source-projects/scrot). You can also pull the binary off an existing Ubuntu install.

It's super simple to run:

```bash
alan@ziggy:~$ scrot
alan@ziggy:~$ ls -l 2024-03-25-102129_3840x2280_scrot.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 25659 Mar 25 10:21 2024-03-25-102129_3840x2280_scrot.png
alan@ziggy:~$ file 2024-03-25-102129_3840x2280_scrot.png
2024-03-25-102129_3840x2280_scrot.png: PNG image data, 3840 x 2280, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions, the `gnome-screenshot` tool remains available for installation in current Ubuntu versions. It works correctly with Wayland.